# Probability question about spheres and boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$N$ uniform spheres are to be segregated into $4$ boxes labelled $A,B,C,D$. What is the probability of not finding a sphere in box A if :

$1.\:  N=4$

$2. \: N=10$

?

According to me , if they are the spheres and boxes are represented by $X$ and $*$ respectively and  listed as a string eg. $XX*X*X*$ (Actually the $*$ represents the separation between regions that represent a box i.e. two spheres in each box would be shown as- $XX*XX*XX*XX)$, the no. of ways in which they could be segregated is $\binom{10 +4-1}{10}$ where $10$ is the no. of spheres and in this case the $10$ spaces in the resultant $13$ character string.

Subsequently, if one box is ignored as per the requirement of the question , the required probability should be :  $\frac{\binom{10+3-1}{10}}{\binom{10+4-1}{10}}$

Please provide an answer to the probability question and any mistakes that I may have made in my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems right to me (assuming your question is whether or not your reasoning is right.)

**EDIT:**
Actually, the answer depends on the way you distribute the spheres. If you choose a box for each sphere at random, the answer is different than the one you give, because you assume every distribution of spheres has the same probability.

When a random box is chosen for each separate sphere, the distribution $(1,1,1,1)$ is $4!=24$ times more likely than $(4,0,0,0)$. The probability that box $A$ (or any other specified box) is empty is just
$$
\left(\frac 34\right)^n
$$
in that case.

Comment: That is a part of my question. I'd like your answer/approach too

Comment: @JaneLove updated my answer. What exactly is 'random' in your case?

Comment: I'm not sure what was random my self. But the answer you gave is the correct answer. I simply knew the model of this question and applied the concept I had learnt for this model.